# Disjoin Domain missing redirect folders

Tags: folder-redirection

op.system is windows 7. i dis join the domain to **Workgroup** and now from the local account i can´t see the redirected folders Desktop and Documents. The domain i can´t rejoin. is it possible some how to make see the folders and get data back?

Link that i have used for solution and dint help. [Link](https://www.google.co.th/?gws_rd=cr&ei=rOZLU5_5BpGi8AWGvoKABA#q=disjoin%20domain%20missing%20desktop)

all solutions are welcome

Answer (score 1):

If you were part of a domain that uses folder redirection to their server, you obviously have no access anymore to get this content after you leave the domain. Your only option is to create a new local user (or if there is such, you don't have to create one of course) and log in with it.

*Note: your current account disjoined from the domain is* ***NOT*** *a local account, but rather a cached network account.*

Logging in on a domain account, even using off-line, while it has redirected folders turned on, will not work unless those folders are set to download for off-line use. Note that if the offline-storage cache is corrupt, it will keep using the online version and the folders will disappear after you disjoin the domain.

How to fix? The only way is to rejoin the domain, or ask one of the ICT guys to give you the data.